# ASP.NET MVC View classes and null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper-6

I have a complex structure with nested view model classes:

```
public class ApplicationDriverFormVM : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Sign { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDriverAddressFormVM PresentAddress { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationDriverAddressFormVM> PreviousAddresses { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDriverLicenseFormVM License { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDriverEducationFormVM Education { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationDriverAdditionalLicenseFormVM> AdditionalLicenses { get; set; }


    //public ApplicationDriverAccidentFormVM DefaultAccident { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationDriverAccidentFormVM> Accidents { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationDriverTrafficConvictionFormVM> TrafficConvictions { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationDriverEmployerFormVM> Employers { get; set; }


    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorFormVM EquipmentTractor { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentTrailerFormVM EquipmentTrailer { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentStraightTruckFormVM EquipmentStraightTruck { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentCargoVanFormVM EquipmentCargoVan { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDriverFormVM()
    {
        PresentAddress = new ApplicationDriverAddressFormVM();
        PreviousAddresses = new List<ApplicationDriverAddressFormVM>();
        PreviousAddresses.Add(new ApplicationDriverAddressFormVM());
        License = new ApplicationDriverLicenseFormVM();
        Education = new ApplicationDriverEducationFormVM();
        AdditionalLicenses = new List<ApplicationDriverAdditionalLicenseFormVM>();
        AdditionalLicenses.Add(new ApplicationDriverAdditionalLicenseFormVM());
        Accidents = new List<ApplicationDriverAccidentFormVM>();
        Accidents.Add(new ApplicationDriverAccidentFormVM());
        TrafficConvictions = new List<ApplicationDriverTrafficConvictionFormVM>();
        TrafficConvictions.Add(new ApplicationDriverTrafficConvictionFormVM());
        Employers = new List<ApplicationDriverEmployerFormVM>();
        Employers.Add(new ApplicationDriverEmployerFormVM());
        EquipmentTractor = new ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorFormVM();
        EquipmentTrailer = new ApplicationDriverEquipmentTrailerFormVM();
        EquipmentStraightTruck = new ApplicationDriverEquipmentStraightTruckFormVM();
        EquipmentCargoVan = new ApplicationDriverEquipmentCargoVanFormVM();
    }
}
```

And each of them nested classes can have nested classes too...

Problem is many of these classes do not have any required field, so, client can leave all fields of some class as empty. In result, controller gets object like this:

[image]

AutoMapper maps this class to domain (and then infrastructure) class and each entity saves in DB as different record in appropriate table. But I don't want to save empty records, I want to not map them to domain classes. How to do it? Validate each object for null of all its property or there is more strong solution?